# Detect client-side page socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client

I'm creating a game application with a lobby. When the owner clicks "start" all of the lobby members are redirected to the game page. I have special socket.io disconnect code for the lobby page and the game page. How can I detect which page the client is coming from?

For clarification, it shouldn't be able to be modified client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url of the client through

```
socket.handshake.headers.referer
```

and parse it with url.parse().

Answer (score 0):

You want detect client ip address or something else?

Comment: Plus, i don't know how to comment question, so i just give an answer, i'll delete this later.

Comment: You need 50 reputation to comment. :)